# JPA or Play Framework list from query joining 2 tables

Tags: jpa, playframework

Mainly I work with JSF so am totally new to this annotation subject

If anyone can help

I wanna a list from this query

```
SELECT  f.CODE  ,f.NAME || '-' || e.NAME  
FROM FS.ELIGIBLE e  RIGHT
OUTER JOIN FS.FINANCIAL_SUPPORT f ON e.CODE = f.CODE ;
```

The query above retrieves a list from 2 tables and concatenating the name  field from both tables!!

How can i do this in JPA or in play with another query supported by Play Framework ???

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/home), specifically the part about [JPA and your Domain Model](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/jpa#finding).

You can access the entity manager at any time by calling

```
EntityManager entityManager = JPA.em();
```

Using this you can create any query that you want, even a "Native" Query. For example:

```
List<Object> results = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT  f.CODE  ,f.NAME || '-' || e.NAME "+
    "FROM FS.ELIGIBLE e  RIGHT "+
    "OUTER JOIN FS.FINANCIAL_SUPPORT f ON e.CODE = f.CODE").getResultList()
```

Comment: This will work, but I always find it a bit frustrating to have such a huge library stack for persistence, just to resort to native SQL in the end, even for the simplest queries (why not just use JDBC instead?). Isn't there a more elegant solution using JPA?

Comment: @LukasEder Don't agree with you. High-level abstractions make simple things really simple and save a lot of time writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is not like relational database system which you can do your queries like join,  left join or outer joins it is a mapping technology of objects. You can also do the same fetch just like those RDBMS counterparts but with a different approach.

What you have to do is make an Object then relate your second Object to your first Object, that is the proper way to relate 2 or more Objects. The Objects I'm talking about is your Table. See my example below:

1. Table1: Items.java
2. ...
3. // do your imports here ...
4. // do your annotations here like
5. @Entity
6. @Table(name="Items")
7. public class Items implements Serializable {
8. private String id;
9. private String itemno;
10. private String description;
11. private Set<Vendors> vendors;      //this is the 2nd table (1:n relationship)
12. ...
13. // don't forget your constructor
14. // in your setter and getter for Vendors do the ff:
15. @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
16. @JoinColumn(name="id")
17. public Set<Vendors> getVendors() {
18. return vendors;
19. }
20. public void setVendors(Set<Vendors> vendors) {
21. this.vendors = vendors;
22. }
23. ...
24. }

Table2: Vendors.java

1. @Entity
2. @Table(name="Vendors")
3. public class Vendors implements Serializable {
4. private long   id;
5. private String company;
6. private String contact;
7. private String  sequence;
8. ...
9. public Vendors() {  }
10. ...
11. // in your setter & getter
12. @Id
13. public long getId() {
14. return id;
15. }
16. public void setId(long id) {
17. this.id = id;
18. }
19. ...
20. }

Now on your query, just do a regular select as in the ff:

1. public void makeQuery(String seq) {
2. EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(...);
3. EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
4. TypedQuery<Items> query = em.createQuery("
   SELECT i, j.contact, j.company, j.sequence FROM Items i LEFT OUTER JOIN i.vendors j WHERE i.vendors.sequence = :seq
5. ORDER BY i.id", Items.class);
6. List<Items> items = query.setParameter("sequence", seq).getResultList();
7. ...
8. }

Now you can refer to your 2nd table Vendors by using **items.vendors.company** ... and so on.

One disadvantage with this one is that, JPA make its related objects in the form of Set, see the declaration in Table1 (Items) - private Set vendors. Since it was a Set, the sequence is not in order it was received, unlike using List.

Hope this will help ...

Regards, Nelson Deogracias